# Jquery naming function not working

Tags: jquery, function

I have a jquery function which works fine until I try to name it. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/UaZ65/4/

```
function thumbHover() {
    $('.thumb').hover(function () {
        $('.info-top p').text('Hover Text');
    },
    function () {
        if (!$('.info-top p').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.info-top p').text('');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just fine. Your only problem is that your function isn't called.

Make a `thumbHover();` at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/UaZ65/7/

Answer (score 1):

Your `thumbHover()` function is not called. Just remove your function or call it properly to make your code work.

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaZ65/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $('.info-top p').text('Hover Text');
   },
     function() {
     if (!$('.info-top p').hasClass('active')) {
         $('.info-top p').text('');
     }
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UaZ65/5/)